# How to declare a function callback that accepts multiple parameters in Dart/Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, callback

```
final ValueSetter<int> setVal;
```

can be assigned a function callback that accepts one parameter like

```
setVal=(i){
     //assign i to some variable
            }
```

What if I wanted the callback to accept 2 parameters like

```
  setVal=(i,j){
         //assign i and j to some variable
                }
```

?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Variables of type `Function` can be declared as follows:

```
void main() {
  void Function(int) setVal1;
  void Function(int, int) setVal2;

  setVal1 = (int i) => print('$i');
  setVal2 = (int i, int j) => print('$i, $j');
  final String Function(int, int, [double]) setVal3 =
      (int i, int j, [double k]) => '$i, $j, $k';

  final i = 0;
  final j = 1;
  final double k = 2.0;
  setVal1(i);
  setVal2(i, j);
  print(setVal3(i, j));
  print(setVal3(i, j, k));
}
```

Comment: Okay so how do I make the second parameter optional?

Comment: @MichelThomas you accepted this answer even it does not answer your question?

Comment: @MichelThomas Ha-ha. This was an example of `How to declare a function callback(s) that accepts multiple parameters in Dart/Flutter`. Including an additional answer to the question asked in the comments about `how to make the second parameter optional`. Yeah...

Answer (score 4):

ValueSetter is typedef'ed as:

```
typedef ValueSetter<T> = void Function(T value);
```

As in, a function that takes one parameter.  So, no, you can't hand it a function that takes two parameters.

Answer (score 2):

```
final Function(int, String) = (int a, String b){
  /* do stuff */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just put whatevery you want in a map and pass the map. Something like this:

```
  Map<String, dynamic> updateMap = {
    'id': id,
    'value': value


  widget.onUpdate(updateMap);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare your own type, just add this def in your helpers.dart file:

```
typedef ValueSetter2<T, E> = void Function(T value, E value2);
```